# Password dialog doesn't work on lock screen 14.04

Tags: 14.04, password, lock-screen

I have a two-monitors configuration.

Sometimes after a long period the passord dialog on lock screen doesn't work. Input control doesn't appear. Is may happen in one or both monitor dialogs.

What can I do?

Comment: but you see the window? I mean your username is displayed but no input box, correct?

Comment: Correct, that's what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known "bug"

you can do the following workaround :

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to VT1

enter your username and password and run

```
unity --replace
```

switch back using:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>F7</kbd>

Sometimes the top bar disappeared which can be resolved using :

```
compiz --replace
```

Also a simple `unity` will restart your unity...

For me this works, but I heard from others, that they couldn't see the top bar using `compiz --replace`

Comment: `compiz --replace` worked for me in a console back in graphic mode. Thank you.

Comment: These variants didn't work for me. At least from VT1 I can issue a "reboot" command and get a relatively clean restart.